# Rsa encrypted via php giving symbols in vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, rsa

im trying to crypt string in php decrypt it in vb.net

same key (xml converted to pem)

here is my php code

```
$source = "Baselsayeh!@#312";
echo "Source: $source";
$fp=fopen("publicKey.pem","r");
$pub_key=fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
openssl_get_publickey($pub_key);
$hh = $source;
openssl_public_encrypt($hh,$crypttext,$pub_key);
$crypttext = base64_encode($crypttext);
echo "String crypted: " . $crypttext;
```

and here is my vb.net code

```
Function Decrypt(ByVal strCipherText As String, _
ByVal strPrivateKey As String) As String
    Dim rsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim bytPlainText() As Byte
    Dim bytCipherText() As Byte
    Dim uEncode As New UnicodeEncoding()
    rsa.FromXmlString(strPrivateKey)
    bytCipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(strCipherText)
    bytPlainText = rsa.Decrypt(bytCipherText, False)
    Decrypt = uEncode.GetString(bytPlainText)
    rsa.Clear()
End Function
```

any encrypted string giving 慂敳獬祡桥䀡㌣㈱

but encrypt in vb.net and decrypt in php works fine

Comment: What is the character encoding? Is it the same in both systems?

Comment: That means you're either crypting wrong, or decrypting wrong. The crypt algorithms don't care if the key is correct. It's all basically just math, and entirely up to you provide the right numbers to make it all "work". That also means things like b64-encoding on one  side and not b64-decoding on the other can affect all this.

Comment: Jay Blanchard should be same because im using windows

Answer (score 0):

never mind

solved it by using utf8 instaid of unicode

change

```
Dim uEncode As New UnicodeEncoding()
```

to

```
Dim uEncode As New UTF8Encoding()
```